# MATLAB Pasting multiple images in a line onto another image?

Tags: image, matlab, pasting

I am trying to paste multiple smaller images (9 rectangles of different sizes) onto a black background. The center horizontal line of each of these images should be aligned and all the edges should be touching. It doesn't matter where on the black it is pasted as long as they are aligned as described. I will attach some images of what I mean.

example of a smaller image 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8a3hc.png

desired result
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2L4d.jpg

ImageAnalyst provided this great code for pasting images, but I think what I need is a bit more complicated. If anybody can help out or point me to a good direction, I would be very grateful. Many thanks!

```
if true
% % Lets user drag out a box on an image, then define where they want to paste it.
% Then it pastes the drawn region onto the original image.
% Figure out how to select two points for pasting
clc;    % Clear the command window.
close all;  % Close all figures (except those of imtool.)
imtool close all;  % Close all imtool figures.
clear;  % Erase all existing variables.
workspace;  % Make sure the workspace panel is showing.
fontSize = 20;
format compact;
grayImage = imread('Blackout.png');
% Get the dimensions of the image.
% numberOfColorBands should be = 1.
[rows columns numberOfColorBands] = size(grayImage);
% Display the original gray scale image.
subplot(2, 2, 1);
imshow(grayImage);
axis on;
title('Original Grayscale Image', 'FontSize', fontSize);
% Enlarge figure to full screen.
set(gcf, 'units','normalized','outerposition',[0 0 1 1]);
% Display the cropped image.
rotatedImage=imread('rotatedImage.png');
subplot(2, 2, 3);
imshow(rotatedImage);
axis on;
title('Region that you defined', 'FontSize', fontSize);
% Paste it onto the original image
[rows2 columns2] = size(rotatedImage)
promptMessage = sprintf('Click on the upper left point where you want to paste it,\nor                 Cancel to abort processing?'); 
titleBarCaption = 'Continue?';
button = questdlg(promptMessage, titleBarCaption, 'Continue', 'Cancel', 'Continue');
if strcmpi(button, 'Cancel')
return;
end
[x, y] = ginput(1)%pick 1 two-dimensional points from the figure and returns x y     coordinates.
% Determine the pasting boundaries.
r1 = int32(y);
c1 = int32(x);
r2 = r1 + rows2 - 1;
r2 = min([r2 rows]);
c2 = c1 + columns2 - 1;
c2 = min([c2, columns]);
plot([c1 c2 c2 c1 c1], [r1 r1 r2 r2 r1], 'r-');
% Paste as much of croppedImage as will fit into the original image.
grayImage(r1:r2, c1:c2) = rotatedImage(1:(r2-r1+1), 1:(c2-c1+1));
subplot(2, 2, 4);
imshow(grayImage);
axis on;
title('Region that you defined pasted onto original', 'FontSize', fontSize);
%save rotated image
imwrite(grayImage, 'alignedImage.png');
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I think I've figured it out! Just use the row sizes of each of the images to determine the placement of the next image. It's a little messy but I think it's a good start :)

```
% Lets user drag out a box on an image, then define where they want to paste it.
% Then it pastes the drawn region onto the original image.
% Figure out how to select two points for pasting
clc;    % Clear the command window.
close all;  % Close all figures (except those of imtool.)
imtool close all;  % Close all imtool figures.
clear;  % Erase all existing variables.
workspace;  % Make sure the workspace panel is showing.
fontSize = 20;
format compact;
%%
grayImage = imread('Blackout.png');
% Get the dimensions of the image.
% numberOfColorBands should be = 1.
[I1R I1C numberOfColorBands] = size(grayImage);
% Display the original gray scale image.
subplot(1, 3, 1);
imshow(grayImage);
axis on;
title('Original Grayscale Image', 'FontSize', fontSize);
% Enlarge figure to full screen.
set(gcf, 'units','normalized','outerposition',[0 0 1 1]);
%%
% Display the cropped image.
rotatedImage=imread('rotCoxa.png');
subplot(1, 3, 2);
imshow(rotatedImage);
axis on;
title('Region that you defined', 'FontSize', fontSize);
% Paste it onto the original image
[I2R I2C] = size(rotatedImage);
%%
x = 1;
y = I1R/2;
% Determine the pasting boundaries.
r1 = int32(y);
c1 = int32(x);
r2 = r1 + I2R - 1;
r2 = min([r2 I1R]);
c2 = c1 + I2C - 1;
c2 = min([c2, I1R]);
plot([c1 c2 c2 c1 c1], [r1 r1 r2 r2 r1], 'r-');
% Paste as much of croppedImage as will fit into the original image.
grayImage(r1:r2, c1:c2) = rotatedImage(1:(r2-r1+1), 1:(c2-c1+1));
subplot(1, 3, 3);
imshow(grayImage);
axis on;
title('Region that you defined pasted onto original', 'FontSize', fontSize);
%%
%save rotated image
imwrite(grayImage, 'alignedImage.png');
%%
clc;    % Clear the command window.
close all;  % Close all figures (except those of imtool.)
imtool close all;  % Close all imtool figures.
clear;  % Erase all existing variables.
workspace;  % Make sure the workspace panel is showing.
fontSize = 20;
format compact;
%%
%delete('Blackout.png');
grayImage = imread('alignedImage.png');
% Get the dimensions of the image.
% numberOfColorBands should be = 1.
[I1R I1C numberOfColorBands] = size(grayImage);
% Display the original gray scale image.
subplot(1, 3, 1);
imshow(grayImage);
axis on;
title('Original Grayscale Image', 'FontSize', fontSize);
% Enlarge figure to full screen.
set(gcf, 'units','normalized','outerposition',[0 0 1 1]);
%%
% Display the cropped image.
rotatedImage=imread('rotTrochanter.png');
subplot(1, 3, 2);
imshow(rotatedImage);
axis on;
title('Region that you defined', 'FontSize', fontSize);
% Paste it onto the original image
[I3R I3C] = size(rotatedImage);
%%
previouslyrotatedImage=imread('rotCoxa.png');
[I2R I2C] = size(previouslyrotatedImage);
x = I2C;
y = I1R/2 + I2R/2 - I3R; %check math. I3R/2 or I3R?
% Determine the pasting boundaries.
r1 = int32(y);
c1 = int32(x);
r2 = r1 + I3R - 1;
r2 = min([r2 I1R]);
c2 = c1 + I3C - 1;
c2 = min([c2, I1C]);
plot([c1 c2 c2 c1 c1], [r1 r1 r2 r2 r1], 'r-');
% Paste as much of croppedImage as will fit into the original image.
grayImage(r1:r2, c1:c2) = rotatedImage(1:(r2-r1+1), 1:(c2-c1+1));
subplot(1, 3, 3);
imshow(grayImage);
axis on;
title('Region that you defined pasted onto original', 'FontSize', fontSize);
%%
%save rotated image
imwrite(grayImage, 'alignedImage.png');
```